# Android Runtime error on logcat

Tags: java, android, logcat

When i want to test my project in avd emulator i got this following error on logcat that make the application has stopped

```
09-25 12:28:37.495: D/AndroidRuntime(931): Shutting down VM
09-25 12:28:37.495: W/dalvikvm(931): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a122a0)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mira.canyoutapit/com.mira.canyoutapit.Ablankscreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.mira.canyoutapit.Ablankscreen.onCreate(Ablankscreen.java:20)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  ... 11 more
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  ... 23 more
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3273)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:421)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:184)
09-25 12:28:37.525: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  ... 26 more
09-25 12:28:41.985: I/Process(931): Sending signal. PID: 931 SIG: 9
```

can anyone tell me what is that mean of the following error? so i can fix the error from my project

Thank's

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: @GeorgeThomas which code?

Comment: @MD so how to fix that?

Comment: Most likely you are trying to load is too large `Drawable`.

Comment: your images are bigger for example xxxx*xxxx or xxxx*xxx where "x" represents numbers- always go for 500*500 as your max

Answer (score 0):

According to the log you posted, it may be caused by:

1. Open a very large image.
2. Open too many images without release them.

Or other reason, depends on your implementation, in that case you'd better declare your intention and post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:largeHeap="true"` in **manifest** file and reduce resolution of images which you used